unable to remove the header in expo react native
I was trying to create a signup page. I Donot want to show the header in signup page.
the file structure is
app

(admin)
(auth)
layout
index

the layout file content is given below
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
const RootLayout = () => {
return (
<Stack>
<Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
<Stack.Screen name="(admin)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
<Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
</Stack>
);
};
export default RootLayout;

The header is not showing in (admin) and index.tsx. But it is visible in (auth) group.
I was trying to remove the header from signup page. But the header shows as "(auth)/(signup)/index".
How can I remove the header.

Remove the (auth) from Stacknavigator and make it a standalone screen.

You can try adding the following in the JSX for the sign-up screen since it is nested within the (auth) folder:
<Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} />

Another option could be to define a layout for the (auth) folder and hide the header over there (as you have done for the root layout).
